# Not picking values after 4th row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I m trying to get columns value of table on a single row click and then populate them into input fields.

```
$(function(){
    $('#prd_table').find('tbody > tr').click(function(){
        var selectID = $('#'+($(this).index()+1));  

        $('#sifra').val(selectID.children().eq(1).text());
        $('#title').val(selectID.children().eq(2).text());
        $('#em').val(selectID.children().eq(3).text());
        $('#price').val(selectID.children().eq(4).text());
    });
});
```

**Check it here:**
https://jsfiddle.net/4p77thq3/

This script works only for the first 4 rows. I am new in JavaScript programming. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're not assigning an IDs to the 5th and onward rows.

```
<tr id="5">...</tr>
<tr id="6">...</tr>
...
```

A simpler solution to this would be to just use `$(this)` to get the correct row.

```
var selectID = $(this);
```

Comment: Oh silly me. Wasted too much time looking for a clue in JS. Thanks much